# how to make two rows to single row based on index in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert data frame with two rows as single row. here i am placing tables for better understanding.

This is my actual output

[image]

how to convert above table to single row (see below table)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `MultiIndex Series`, convert to one column DataFrame by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose for one row `DataFrame`, last flatten `MultiIndex` by `join`:

```
df1 = s.set_index('Gender').stack().to_frame().T
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]} {x[1]}')
```